# Column closingevent.id doesn't exist LINE 1: SELECT "closingevent"."id", "closingevent"."owner", "closing

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

I've a problem with my templates. I try to render the following template

```
{% if liste_column %}
<table> 
    <tr><th>Owner</th>
        <th>RegimeID</th>
        <th>ClosingeventID</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Transaction or Closing</th>
        <th>**** Accounting Field</th>
        <th>Data Source</th>
    </tr>

{% for item in liste_column %}
    <tr><td>{{item.owner}}</td>
        <td>{{item.regimeid}}</td>
        <td>{{item.closingeventid}}</td>
        <td>{{item.category}}</td>
        <td>{{item.transactionorclosing}}</td>
        <td>{{item.****accountingfield}}</td>
        <td>{{item.datasource}}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% else %}
    <p>No Data are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And get the error:

```
Column closingevent.id doesn't exist LINE 1: SELECT "closingevent"."id", "closingevent"."owner", "closing...
```

My table has no column which is called "closingevent"."id" and I even didn't try to get this. I get it for other templates too.

Can you help me? I think it could be the problem that my model doesn't have a primary key and just a foreign key.

```
class Closingevent(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    regimeid = models.ForeignKey('Regime', models.DO_NOTHING, 
    db_column='regimeid')
    closingeventid = models.FloatField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    closingevent = models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    transactionorclosing = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    ****accountingfield = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    datasource = models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    debitacoountnumber = models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=True,         
    null=True)
    debitsubitem = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    debitaccountname = models.ForeignKey('Lineitemaccounting',     
    models.DO_NOTHING,db_column='debitaccountname', 
    blank=True,null=True,related_name='daccountname2')
    debitbalancesheet = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    debitprofitandlose = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    debitreconciliation = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    creditaccountnumber = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    creditsubitem = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    creditaccountname = models.ForeignKey('Lineitemaccounting', 
    models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='creditaccountname', blank=True, 
    null=True,related_name='caccountname2')
    creditbalancesheet = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    creditprofitandloss = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    creditreconciliation = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, 
    null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'closingevent'
        unique_together = (('regimeid', 'closingeventid'),)
```

Comment: `id` is auto-generated by Django since you did not provide any primary key field and what is this syntax (`****accountingfield...`)

Comment: Have you run the relevant migrations?

Comment: The stars just for disguising "sensitive" data.
Yeah I run all migrations.
Just to make sure:
manage.py makemigrations display
manage.py sqlmigrate display 0001
manage.py migrate